# Select a dropdown element with dynamic ID using Webdriver, C#

Tags: c#, xpath, dynamic, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a situation I'm trying to handle. I am using webdriver, C#. when I tried using the CSSSelector it is just reading the parameter as a string. Kindly look into it.This is the HTML.

```
<div class="select2-container select2" id="s2id_UserRole" style="width: 100%;">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
***<span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-7">&nbsp;</span>***
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen7" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
<input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-7" id="s2id_autogen7">
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">   
<div class="select2-search">       
<label for="s2id_autogen7_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>       
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-7" id="s2id_autogen7_search" placeholder="">   
</div>   
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-7">   </ul></div>
</div>
```

The element I'm trying to get the ID is a dropdown with this kind of ID: `id="select2-chosen-7"`. The "select-chosen-" is static and numeric part is dynamic. After reading forums, all suggestion does not seem to have the answer. At the end this is the code I'm using which is still not working -

```
IWebElement DropDownPath = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("*[id^='select2-chosen-'][id*='select2-chosen-']"));
SelectElement DropDown = new SelectElement(DropDownPath);
DropDown.SelectByText(UserConstants.UserRoleText);
```

Comment: Wow a down vote without telling him what's wrong with this question is quite hard. @Kehinde Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by automatically create the nested loop? Do you want to create code at runtime that does your foreach? If so are there any templates for that dynamically created code?

Comment: Thanks. What I'm trying to do is that there are classes in my project that have foreach statements. To me, this seems to be overused. It is wiser to create just a method like this, and pass in argument and the other classes will override in their implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't a requirement to keep the ValuesAddX separated, you could have an array of arrays, and foreach over that:

```
public static string[][] ValuesAdd = 
    {
        new [] { "a", "b", "c" },
        new [] { "1", "2", "3" },
        new [] { "x", "y", "z" },
    };

public void NestedForeach() 
{
    // Note that count isn't required anymore as we're using
    // ValuesAdd.Length as the count
    NestedForeachRecursive(string.Empty, 0);
}

public void NestedForeachRecursive(string prefix, int depth)
{
    foreach (var item in ValuesAdd[depth])
    {
        var nextDepth = depth + 1;
        var nextPrefix = prefix + item;

        if (nextDepth < ValuesAdd.Length)
            NestedForeachRecursive(nextPrefix, nextDepth);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(nextPrefix);
    }
}
```

Note that because you're iterating over every item for every other item, the performance of this will scale very poorly.

The output of this example is:

```
a1x
a1y
a1z
a2x
a2y
a2z
a3x
a3y
a3z
b1x
b1y
b1z
b2x
... and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use recursion:

```
public void ConutNumber(int count)
{
    ...
    GoThroughElements(count);
    ...
}

public void GoThroughElements(int count, List<String> recurseValues = new List<String>())
{
    foreach(String value in ValuesAdd1)
    {
        recurseValues.Add(value);
        if(count == 1)
        {
            // In deepest recursion iterate through the line of values
            foreach(String i in recurseValues)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        else if(count > 1)
        {
            GoThroughElements(--count, recurseValues);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong count!");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check your count for invalid values. Use recursion with great care, it may easily cause memory issues if a wrong case goes unnoticed.